# Issue using job::job() within RMarkdown file

Tags: r, r-markdown, jobs

I am working on compiling one large RMarkdown file that reproduces all of the analyses for a scientific manuscript. A few of the analyses take a long time, so I've used job::job() to run them as jobs, which has worked great when I'm working through the RMarkdown file in RStudio.

But, I'd like to be able to knit the RMarkdown file to html/pdf to share with the manuscript too. But I get an error in the first chunk that includes a `job::job()` call when trying to render:

> Error in check_available(): ! You must run this from the RStudio main
> session. Backtrace:
>
> job::job(...) job:::check_available() Execution halted

Is there something I'm missing that would make it possible to render the RMarkdown even with the job sections? Or is this just fundamentally incompatible (and if so, any suggestions for how to achieve a similar job-running situation within RMarkdown)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this won't work. Jobs can only be used in an RStudio main session, and you could try using {future} and {callr} instead. See the following quotes:

> `job::job()` is aimed at easing interactive development within RStudio. For tasks that don't benefit from running in the Jobs pane of RStudio, check out:
>
> - The [`future` package](https://future.futureverse.org)'s `%<-%` operator combined with `plan(multisession)`.
> - The [`callr` package](https://callr.r-lib.org/) is a general tool to run code in new R sessions.